# Which minimum dependencies for JAX-RS in WildFly?

Tags: jax-rs, wildfly

We're running a project which is deployed as several WARs in a WildFly 20 server. The project setup is horrible due to "historic reasons", i.e. there are several `pom.xml` files with dependencies all over the place.

Now I'm about to build a new WAR module which shall provide a REST API based on JAX-RS. As I can start from scratch, I'd like to keep the `pom.xml` as simple as possible by using the libraries which WildFly 20 already provides.

This is a sample controller:

**SampleController.java**

```java
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;

public class SampleController {

    @GET
    public Response ping() {
        return Response.ok().entity("pong").build();
    }
}
```

It seems as if the following is working:

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
        <artifactId>javax.ws.rs-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.1</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

But this is also working...

```xml
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jakarta.platform</groupId>
        <artifactId>jakarta.jakartaee-api</artifactId>
        <version>${jakartaee.version}</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

And then I'm reading about including `wildfly-jaxrs` and other artifacts...

So, which dependencies do I really need specififcally for implementing REST services with JAX-RS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using a Jakarta EE Compatible server, WildFly, the API is all you would need as a dependency. The dependency should also be marked as `<scope>provided</scope>`.

Given this is a new application I'd lean towards using the Jakarta EE dependencies.